# Changing panel backgrounds with a borderlayout Manager

Tags: java, swing, background-color, panels, border-layout

I am trying to set my buttons to change the panel background color in which the buttons reside using a borderlayout manager. I have no problems when I use flowlayout but can't figure it out with the border layout. I feel like I am missing something fundamental. I have found similar threads with panels and color changing but none have been able to answer my question. Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.awt.*;     // Needed for BorderLayout class
import javax.swing.*;  // Needed for Swing classes
import java.awt.event.*;//Needed for Action Listener


public class BorderPanelWindow extends JFrame
{
   public BorderPanelWindow()
   { 
      // Set the title bar text.
      setTitle("Border Layout");

      // Specify an action for the close button.
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      // Add a BorderLayout manager to the content pane.
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      // Create five panels.
      JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
      JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
      JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
      JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
      JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();

      // Create five buttons.
      JButton rbutton = new JButton("Red");
      JButton bbutton = new JButton("Blue");
      JButton gbutton = new JButton("Green");
      JButton ybutton = new JButton("Yellow");
      JButton obutton = new JButton("Orange");

      //create actions for the buttons
      ColorChanger yellowAction = new ColorChanger(Color.YELLOW); 
      ColorChanger redAction = new ColorChanger(Color.RED); 
      ColorChanger blueAction = new ColorChanger(Color.BLUE);
      ColorChanger greenAction = new ColorChanger(Color.GREEN);
      ColorChanger orangeAction = new ColorChanger(Color.ORANGE);

      //set actions for the buttons
      rbutton.addActionListener(redAction);
      bbutton.addActionListener(blueAction);
      gbutton.addActionListener(greenAction);
      ybutton.addActionListener(yellowAction);
      obutton.addActionListener(orangeAction);


      // Add the buttons to the panels.
      panel1.add(rbutton);
      panel2.add(bbutton);
      panel3.add(gbutton);
      panel4.add(ybutton);
      panel5.add(obutton);

      // Add the five panels to the content pane.
      add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      add(panel3, BorderLayout.EAST);
      add(panel4, BorderLayout.WEST);
      add(panel5, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      // Pack and display the window.
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }

   private class ColorChanger implements ActionListener 
   { 
      //fields
      private Color backgroundColor;

      //constructor
      public ColorChanger(Color c) 
      { 
         backgroundColor = c; 
      } 


      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
      {
         setBackground(backgroundColor); 
      }  

   } 



   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       new BorderPanelWindow();
   }
}
```

I've managed to get the code to compile

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: how can I change the panel background color with the buttons that reside in each panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < getContentPane().getComponentCount(); i++) {
            getContentPane().getComponent(i).setBackground(backgroundColor);
        }
    }
```

You are changing the color of `JFrame` which is parent of all `JPanel` that is added into it. You have to set the background color of all `JPanel` added into it.

---

--EDIT--

As per your last comment - *I only want the region where the buttons reside to change color*

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
            ((JButton) e.getSource()).getParent().setBackground(backgroundColor);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ur awesome! that was a huge help, but could you help me understand it. I don't understand how/what getContentPane().getComponent(i) is referencing?

Comment: Read it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RootPaneContainer.html)

Comment: Directly from JavaDoc of [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) that says: *The content pane provided by the root pane should, as a rule, contain all the non-menu components displayed by the JFrame. This is different from the AWT Frame case. As a conveniance add and its variants, remove and setLayout have been overridden to forward to the contentPane as necessary.*

Comment: Sry disregard my previous post. that's close but I only want the region where the buttons reside to change color?

Comment: Find updates in my post. Get the parent of `JButton` that is a `JPanel` and change the background color.

Comment: ok that i understand. never would have that to use instanceof. you've been a huge help Braj.

Comment: Its a good practice to use `instanceof` operator before any casting operation. In this program you know it but in a bigger application it can break.